# How do I install these packages?

Tags: react-native, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native-maps

I am using android studio for my project and I need to install these packages to use google maps, Can anyone tell me How to check if I already have these packages, and how to install them if I don't have have them already ?

*Extras / Google Play services

Extras / Google Repository

Android 6.0 (API 23) / Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image Rev. 19

Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.3*

Comment: You can check out this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#step_4_add_the_maps_dependency

Answer (score 0):

there you go, you have to go to
(File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK)
and there you find the SDK platform, SDK tools, and SDK update sites.
you can install and update your packages there.

Comment: thank you, I was able to download all those packages